# Looking for a more precise noun than "acceptance"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I want to express that someone who's renowned "has much social acceptance".

But *acceptance* doesn't seem so close in meaning, I've seen another expression elsewhere, just couldn't find it.

Comment: Can you supply some context? Otherwise, this is a pure shot in the dark.

Comment: I can’t parse the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It would depend on context, but *prestige* might fit.

Answer (score 2):

People who are socially accepted enjoy great [popularity](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/popularity) among others.

Answer (score 1):

You're not after [*cachet*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cachet) by any chance? In particular for these senses:

1. an indication of approval carrying great prestige; or simply
2. prestige

I think cachet works best when you're talking about social acceptance within (high) society or when describing position within a particular group, and it's rare enough that using it sort of adds to the feel of exclusivity (cue [obligatory N-gram showing cachet vs prestige, respectability, and acceptance](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cachet%2Cprestige%2Crespectability%2Cacceptance&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for example).

I'd personally use it only if I wanted to hint at that exclusivity and first amongst peers sense, or alternatively if I wanted to give something common a bit more of a sense of being slightly different from the norm, in a good, desirable way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for **repute** or **reputation**.

> He's renowned and has a lot of repute/reputation in the society.

Comment: reputation is closer. 'repute' is somewhat of a '[stormy kestrel](http://www.satiche.org.uk/satiche/sat-0342.htm)'; it usually only ever is mentioned in the context of an 'ill repute' (a poor reputation).

Answer (score 0):

***recognition*** and *acceptance* convey similar, if not the same, meaning in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is *celebrated* is greatly admired or renowned
*-- a celebrated musician*

Answer (score 0):

How about something like one of these two?

“John Smith, renowned for his work in experimental sculpture, has recently received more public notoriety for his philanthropic actions.”

“John Smith, renowned for his work in experimental sculpture, has recently made inroads into popular culture with his puppetry.”

Answer (score 0):

The word I would use is social **respectability**. That's stronger than "social acceptance."